# Get randomly the 3 minimum values of an repeated-values array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I've an array `my_array` and I want, due to specific reasons ignore the values -5 and -10 of it (yes, in the example below there's not a `-10` but in other arrays I've to manage yes), and get the index of the three minimum values of the array, and append them to a new list titled `lista_indices_candidatos`.

This is my code.

```
my_array = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]
a = np.array(my_array) 
indices = a.argsort()
indices = indices[a[indices] != -5]
indices = indices[a[indices] != -10]
lista_indices_candidatos = []
for i in indices[:3]:
    lista_indices_candidatos.append(i)
print lista_indices_candidatos
```

This gets me the index of the 3 minimum values `[6, 0, 3]` from the array `[4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]`

The thing is that, if there are repeated values, this get's me the first three minimum values (the first `4` (index 0) the second `4` (index 3), ignoring the rest `4`'s of the array.

How can I change the code to get completely randomly the three minimum values, without taking always the first three?

Comment: You could shuffle the whole list.

Comment: Strange thing to want.  That would mean that in your case you want the index of the `0` and then two indexes of any of the `4` values?  So, `[6, 7, 8]` would be fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```
import random

def eachIndexSorted(a):  # ... without -5 and -10
  for value in sorted(set(a) - { -5, -10 }):
    indexes = [ i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == value ]
    random.shuffle(indexes)
    for i in indexes:
      yield i

def firstN(iterator, n):
  for i in range(n):
    yield iterator.next()

print list(firstN(eachIndexSorted(my_array), 3))
```

If you have very large data, then sorting the complete set might be too costly; finding each next minimum iteratively might then be a better approach.  (Ask for more details if this aspect is unclear and important for you.)

Answer (score 1):

myArray = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]

myUniqueArray = list(set(myArray))

myUniqueArray.sort()

return [myArray.index(myUniqueArray[0]), myArray.index(myUniqueArray[1]), myArray.index(myUniqueArray[2])]

.index would not give you a random index in the sense that it will always be the same value for a give set of input list but you could play with that part.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't introduced randomness, because it don't really see the point for doing this.

If you need the **first 3 lowest positive values**:

```
sorted([x for x in my_array if x >= 0])[:3]
```

If you need the **first three lowest positive values and their initial index**:

```
sorted([(x,idx) for idx,x in enumerate(my_array) if x >= 0], key=lambda t: t[0])[:3]
```

If you just need the **first 3 lowest positive values initial indexes**:

```
[i for x,i in sorted([(x,idx) for idx,x in enumerate(my_array) if x >= 0], key=lambda t: t[0])[:3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My take is that you want to get 3 random indices for values in my_array, excluding [-10, -5], the 3 random indices must be chosen within the index list of the 3 lowest values of the remaining set, right?

What about this:

```
from random import sample
my_array = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]
sample([i for i, x in enumerate(my_array) if x in sorted(set(my_array) - {-10, -5})[:3]], 3)
```

Factoring out the limited set of values, that would be:

```
from random import sample

my_array = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]
filtered_list = sorted(set(my_array) - {-10, -5})[:3]

# Print 3 sample indices from my_array
print sample([i for i, x in enumerate(my_array) if x in filtered_list], 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that wuth the 3 indices of the example it should return `6`(the index of the `0`) and other two. Your solutions sometimes doent get that `6` index.

Comment: @borja Well, that's what randomness is for through "sample()". Of course, one would have to seed the random number generator for more entropy, i.e. more randomness. Unless I haven't understood what you meant by "randomly". My question then boils down to: do you want only 3 indices or *all* indices, suffled of the lowest 3 values.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'm also not sure what you are trying to achieve.  I like the simplicity of Nasha's answer, but I think you want to always have the index of the 0 in the result set.  The way I understand you, you want the index of the lowest three values and only if one of those values is listed more than once, do you want to pick randomly from those.

Here's my try a solution:

```
import random

my_array = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]
my_dict = {}
lista_indices_candidatos = []

for index, item in enumerate(my_array):
    try:
        my_dict[item] = my_dict[item] + [index]
    except:
        my_dict[item] = [index]

for i in [x for x in sorted(my_array) if x != -10 and x != -5][:3]:
    lista_indices_candidatos.append(random.choice(my_dict[i]))

print lista_indices_candidatos
```

In this solution, I build a dictionary with all the values from `my_array` as keys.  The values of the dictionary is a list of indexes these numbers have in `my_array`.  I then use a list comprehension and slicing to get the three lowest values to iterate over in the `for` loop.  There, I can randomly pick an index for a given value by randomly selecting from `my_dict`.

I bet there are better ways to achieve what you want to achieve, though.  Maybe you can let us know what it is you are trying to do so we can improve on our answers.

After reading your comment, I see that you do not actually want a completely random selection, but instead a random selection without repetition.  So here's an updated version.

```
import random

my_array = [4, -5, 10, 4, 4, 4, 0, 4, 4]
my_dict = {}
lista_indices_candidatos = []

for index, item in enumerate(my_array):
    try:
        my_dict[item] = my_dict[item] + [index]
    except:
        my_dict[item] = [index]

for l in my_dict:
    random.shuffle(my_dict[l])

for i in [x for x in sorted(my_array) if x != -10 and x != -5][:3]:
    lista_indices_candidatos.append(my_dict[i].pop())

print lista_indices_candidatos
```

Comment: This sometimes returns duplicated index, `[6, 7, 7]`, for example.